# It is not outputting what was expected and am unsure as to the issue

Tags: c, printf

I have just started with C and am slowly learning it, but after reviewing this for hours and consulting others I cant seem to find the issue. When I run it I am expecting to be able to type in 5 numbers and then get back wether they are odd or even and then how many were odd and how many were even. With that said, it doesnt seem to work and always outputs some really big number and im not sure why or where it is getting it from. Is someone able to help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
    int num5;
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;

    printf("Input the first integer.\n");
    scanf("%i", &num1);
    printf("Input the second integer.\n");
    scanf("%i", &num2);
    printf("Input the third integer.\n");
    scanf("%i", &num3);
    printf("Input the fourth integer.\n");
    scanf("%i", &num4);
    printf("Input the fifth integer.\n");
    scanf("%i", &num5);

    if (num1/2 == 0)
        {
        printf("%i is even.\n", &num1);
        even++;
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%i is odd.\n", &num1);
        odd++;
        }
    if (num2/2 == 0)
        {
        printf("%i is even.\n", &num2);
        even++;
        }
    else
        {
        odd++;
        printf("%i is odd.\n", &num2);
        }
    if (num3/2 == 0)
        {
        printf("%i is even.\n", &num3);
        even++;
        }
    else
        {
        odd++;
        printf("%i is odd.\n", &num3);
        }
    if (num4/2 == 0)
        {
        printf("%i is even.\n", &num4);
        even++;
        }
    else
        {
        odd++;
        printf("%i is odd.\n", &num4);
        }
    if (num5/2 == 0)
        {
        printf("%i is even.\n", &num5);
        even++;
        }
    else
        {
        odd++;
        printf("%i is odd.\n", &num5);
        }

    printf("%i numbers are even.\n", &even);
    printf("%i numbers are odd.\n", &odd);
}
```

[image: The output is this and idk why...]

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in the print statements, you're passing the address of the variable which you want to print. This actually invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the conversion specifier (`%d`) and the supplied argument type (`int *`) do not match.

Change

```
 printf("%i is even.\n", &num1);
```

to

```
printf("%i is even.\n", num1);
```

and likewise.

That said,

1. You need to use modulo operator `%` to check the remainder, not the  division operator.
2. You should really consider using a function to determine the odd and even numbers, so as to avoid repeating the same login multiple times in the code.

Comment: Ok it got rid of the horrendous numbers but is not saying any numbers are even.

Comment: I think undefined behavior description isn't accurate. The behavior is defined to get you the address where the variables lies in memory. It's more accurate in my opinion to say that the **exact output** is undefined.

Comment: @Youssef13 **No, it's undefined behavior**. You must use `%p` and cast the argument to `(void *)`, if you really need to print the address.

Comment: Alright I fixed it thankyou very much, it was to do with the operation in the if. I was dividing the number by 2 and only if it = 0 then it would be even but it needed to be % instead of / for the remainder to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the **variable memory address** instead of the variable value itself. That is what the ampersand (`&`) does, it gives you **an address**. That is why you need it in `scanf`, `scanf` needs to know **where** the variable **in memory** to be able to put the user input in it. But when printing, you need to print the value itself. so don't use the `&` in such a case.

You have another logical-error in your code. When you check for number whether it's even or odd, you want to check the remainder value, not the division value. so use `%` instead of `/`.